# How to determine the location of the main man page directory

Tags: bash, software-installation, scripts, manpage

I have an install script for a little program (script) that comes with man pages.

How can I find the location (full path) of the main man page directory?

As `manpath` gives me a list of directories, I would like a command to get a single directory and in best case the main one in order to copy man-files there.

Comment: manpages' main directory is always `/usr/share/man` as defined by the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREMANMANUALPAGES).

Comment: So I can install to /usr/share/man/man1 ? There are no files in /usr/share/man itself.

Comment: yes `man1` is correct, it's in the link directly below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREMANMANUALPAGES) stated that `Manual pages are stored in <mandir>/<locale>/man<section>/<arch>`
With `<mandir>` usually be `/usr/share/man`, and the `man<section>` that fits best with your case is `man1`:
`man1: User programs Manual pages that describe publicly accessible commands are contained in this chapter. Most program documentation that a user will need to use is located here.`
Other attributes in the path can be found in the standard.

So yes, you can save your man files straight in `/usr/share/man/man1`, but try to save it in a more specific path to comply with the standard and to, quote from above standard link, "support manual pages which are written in different (or multiple) languages. These provisions must take into account the storage and reference of these manual pages. Relevant factors include language (including geographical-based differences), and character code set".

Answer (score 2):

The man command itself can show the location of a man page with the -w and the -W options.

Here's an excerpt of man's man from Ubuntu 16.04:

```
       -w, --where, --path, --location
              Don't actually display the manual pages, but do print the location(s) of the  source  nroff  files
              that would be formatted.

       -W, --where-cat, --location-cat
              Don't  actually display the manual pages, but do print the location(s) of the cat files that would
              be displayed.  If -w and -W are both specified, print both separated by a space.
```